# User inputs 3x3 Matrix in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, calculator, matrix-multiplication

I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double v[3];
    double M[3][3];
    int i,j;

    cout << "Enter in the components of vector v:\n";

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        cout << "Component " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> v[i];
    }

    cout << "Enter in the elements of matrix M:\n";

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            cin >> M[i][j];
        }
    }

    double Mv[3];

    Mv[0] = (M[0][0] * v[0]) + (M[0][1] * v[1]) + (M[0][2] * v[2]);
    Mv[1] = (M[1][0] * v[0]) + (M[1][1] * v[1]) + (M[1][2] * v[2]);
    Mv[2] = (M[2][0] * v[0]) + (M[2][1] * v[1]) + (M[2][2] * v[2]);

    cout << "The product of Mv is: " << Mv[3] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When the user enters in the elements of the matrix it simply goes to the next line etc...

How can I make it so that when the user inputs the code, it shows the actual matrix and not just a list of 9 elements.

Comment: I assume the problem is that you input a number, then press the `Enter` key (which is what tells the terminal program to send the input to your program), which puts the cursor on the next line? This is nothing you can really do anything about from your program, unless you want to mess about with manual cursor positioning (which is nothing C++ does, but have to be handled by 3rd-part libraries or OS-specific code).

Comment: Oh and you have an off-by-one error when you attempt to print the array `Mv`, leading to *undefined behavior*. You need a loop to print the array.

Comment: You need a debugger first and foremost.

Comment: How about reading a line at a time as a string, and then parsing the string with something like `strtok()` or `sscanf()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the users. Users can enter the elements of 3x3 matrix with spaces and a new line (after 3 elements):

[image: 3x3 matrix]

Comment: It’s my pleasure.